# Can`t use IE and Chrome WebDrivers after pom.xml added

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver

As requirement for Maven appeared, I added pom.xml to project and converted existing project to Maven one. 
This is my stack trace for IE WebDriver start. Similar I get for Chrome. FF runs perfectly; and this is strange, but Safari also runs.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\yuliya.savytska\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\2.44.0\selenium-ie-driver-2.44.0
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:117)
```

My pom.xml:
`http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple
    webdriverbasics
    jar
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    webdriverbasics
    http://maven.apache.org

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>    
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`

And a call of driver in code:

```
private static WebDriver getDriver(){
    if (driver == null) {
        String browser = getBrowserType(); 

        switch (browser) {
        case "firefox": 
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize(); break;
        case "chrome": 
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
                    "C:\\Users\\yuliya.savytska\\.m2\\repository\\org\\seleniumhq\\selenium\\selenium-chrome-driver\\2.44.0\\selenium-chrome-driver-2.44.0");
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addArguments("test-type");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
            driver.manage().window().maximize(); break;
        case "iexplorer": 
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", 
                    "C:\\Users\\yuliya.savytska\\.m2\\repository\\org\\seleniumhq\\selenium\\selenium-ie-driver\\2.44.0\\selenium-ie-driver-2.44.0");
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); break;
        case "safari":
            DesiredCapabilities dcap = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
            dcap.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);
            driver = new SafariDriver(dcap); break;

        default: throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
    return driver;
}
```

My M2_REPO is on it`s place and these drivers do are as jars on location I mentioned in code. (This way of getting absolute path is for me very stinky, so if ideas about that also that would be perfect)

Before I used ChromeDriver and IEDriver as exe files and without Maven - everything was working properly.

Any ideas what is wrong with my WebDrivers and Maven?

Answer (score 2):

`"webdriver.chrome.driver"`  and `"webdriver.ie.driver"` rather refer to standalone apps that you can download at

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

and

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Safari and Firefox don't require this, so they are running out-of-the-box. You might also need a path to your chrome binary, something like this

`chromeOptions.setBinary(new File("THE PATH TO YOUR CHRMOE BINARY`"));

Comment: Do I understand correctly, jars that maven download for me now are useless and I have to include dependencies to drivers in exe?

Comment: not useless, you need them also, but you also need the exe files

Comment: Yeah, I see. I`ll find how to add dependencies for binaries and try if it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download first chrome driver and ie 32/64 executable files and keep it in some directory. Executable files can not be added in the POM.xml. 
When you are using POM no need to specify the path for jars....POM will do it for you automatically (just add proper dependencies to your pom)

Below example may help you

For Chrome

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\yuliya.savytska\\Desktop\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe")
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

For IE

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\yuliya.savytska\\Desktop\\drivers\\IEDriverServer_x64.exe")
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

Important:
if you initialize for example webdriver.ie.driver (3.0.1) dont forget set dependency selenium-remote-driver

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>guitest</artifactId>
<name>Maven Default Project</name>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-ie-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver/3.0.1